# Ruby on rails, unable to display content of the instance variables

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create the application for course reviews at certain universities. Currently, I have two models which is courses and reviews. I am trying to display the content of the reviews table in courses views but it only displays the address of the content and cannot display actual values. Any help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TgIT.png)

Below is the controller, models and views.

```
course/show.html.erb

<div class = "col-md-7">
    <h2>Tips from other students</h2>
    <%= form_with( model: @course, local: true, class: "col-md-7") do |f| %>
        <% f.fields_for :reviews do |rf| %>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 well ng-scope" ng-repeat="tip in $ctrl.displayCourse.tips track by $index">
                <li class="ng-binding"><%= rf.select :reviews_content, @reviews %></span></li>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

```
/course_controller.rb
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_course, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

    def index
        @courses = Course.all
        @reviews = Review.all
    end

    def new
        @course = Course.new
        @course.reviews.build
    end

    def create
        @course = Course.new(course_params)
        @course.save
        if @course.save
            flash[:success] = "New course has created"
            redirect_to course_path(@course)
        else 
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @reviews = Review.where(course_id: params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
        @course = Course.find(params[:id])
        @course.destroy

        flash[:danger] = "Course was deleted"
        redirect_to courses_path
    end

    def edit
        #@course = Course.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        #@course = Course.find(params[:id])
        if @course.update(course_params)
            flash[:success] = "Course was updated with reviews"
            redirect_to course_path(@course)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private
    def set_course
        @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    end

    def course_params
        params.require(:course).permit(:coursename, :course_content, :prerequisite, :proctoredexams, :groupwork, :textbook, reviews_attributes: [:reviews_content])
    end 

    def review_params
        params.require(:course).permit(reviews_attributes: [:reviews_content])
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/select) for using the `select` form builder method?

Comment: You presumably want to do something like `rf.select :reviews_content, @reviews.collect { |r| [ r.name, r.id ] }`

Answer (score 0):

Your `@reviews` is a collection of objects, and this isn't displayed in the way you want it to be. The `select` tag that you are using, requires a two-dimensional array, for example

```
@reviews.pluck(:title, :id) => [["Sample Review", 1], "Another Review", 2]]
```

This way, the first item of each array ("title") will be displayed in the list, where as the second item ("id") will be the value that's being submitted.